# Order by average rating, but also order by total review count

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-order-by

So currently I have a database query which is ordering my products which are returned, based on the review rating.

```
CASE WHEN p.ApprovedRatingSum > 0 AND p.ApprovedTotalReviews > 0 THEN ((p.ApprovedRatingSum*100)/ p.ApprovedTotalReviews)/5 END DESC
```

I would like to go one further, and order the products that have the same rating value in order of their review count also.
So for products that have 5.0 rating, the highest count will be returned first down to the lowest count.
Something like
- Chair, rating 5.0 (10 reviews)
- table, rating 5.0 (9 reviews)
- sofa, rating 5.0 (7 reviews)
Then so on for each rating value

I'm not strong with databases.
I tried

```
CASE WHEN p.ApprovedRatingSum > 0 AND p.ApprovedTotalReviews > 0 THEN ((p.ApprovedRatingSum*100)/ p.ApprovedTotalReviews)/5 GROUP BY p.ApprovedTotalReviews DESC END DESC
```

and

```
CASE WHEN p.ApprovedRatingSum > 0 AND p.ApprovedTotalReviews > 0 THEN ((p.ApprovedRatingSum*100)/ p.ApprovedTotalReviews)/5 ORDER BY p.ApprovedTotalReviews DESC END DESC
```

But they dont work, feel like there is some database function of something I need to use.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you just need to add another sorting criteria to the query:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN p.ApprovedRatingSum > 0 AND p.ApprovedTotalReviews > 0 
        THEN p.ApprovedRatingSum / p.ApprovedTotalReviews END DESC,
    ApprovedTotalReviews DESC  -- second sort criteria
```

Note that, as far as concerns, you don't need the multiplication/division logic in the first sorting criteria: such linear arithmetic operation are not sensible for sorting.